# How to manage multiple environment in DialogFlow?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

We are currently trying to use DialogFlow system as to make a chatbot. Everything is okay except the fact we couldn't succeed to create Dev / Preprod / Prod with Iso-environment.

As for example :

- We created 3 projects, one for Dev, one for Preprod, one for Prod.
- We tested on PPD before release, copied PPD Dialogflow project with Export.
- Imported it with Import in Prod Project.

However, we discover that the training was not good in Prod because all tests were done on PPD. So we couldn't use Prod at all.

However, we cannot really use PPD for prod because KPI are not same and we also use PPD for Performances tests.

So, does soemone know how to manage different environment with DialogFlow ?

And if not, how to export Training ( We found the Import training function, but not export one )

N.B : We use Japanese as language for information.

Thanks,
BR,
Alexis.

Comment: Thanks for edit :)

Comment: I am not familiar with DialogFlow, but would "Versioning with Import/Export"(https://dialogflow.com/docs/best-practices/import-export-for-versions) work for you?

Comment: hello, Thanks for your help but saddly it does not answer my needs. We already made that but it does not import training. Only intents...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have recently opened environments as experimental feature. May be you wanna check that out. https://dialogflow.com/docs/versions-and-environments
Hope that fulfils your need. **Be sure to use V2 of the API with beta features enabled.** And for that just click on gear icon beside your agent's name.